# Laravel associations, not associating the Models as expected

Tags: php, cakephp, laravel, associations

I'm trying to set up model associations in a Laravel application.  I have a Customer model and a Store model in this example.  Customer has one Store, Store belongs to many Customers.

Customer model:

```
public function store() {
    return $this->hasOne('store', 'store_id');
}
```

Store model:

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('customer', 'store_id');
}
```

Controller call:

```
public function index() {
    $cust = Customer::find('mrowland45');

    echo $cust->store->name;
    exit;
}
```

Error message: Trying to get property of non-object.  So I'm apparently not doing the association correctly?  In CakePHP, you'd set up your association, then when you did a Customer->find(), it would give you something like this:

```
array(
    'Customer' => array(
        //FIELDS SELECTED HERE
    ),
    'Store' => array(
        //FIELDS SELECTED HERE
    )
)
```

so if I did a similar controller call like this, it would work:

```
public function index() {
    $cust = $this->Customer->find('whatever');

    echo $cust['Store']['name'];
    exit;
}
```

Basically, what I want to know is how can I set up the Model associations so that a line of code like this is valid (or if it's even possible...):

```
echo $cust->store->name;
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe the relationships should be customer belongsTo store and store hasMany customers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be laravel's [one to many relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many). That means your customer belongs to a store, but store has many customers.

Models will look like

Customer model

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Store');
}
```

Store Model

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Customer');
}
```

Now you can do.

```
$cust = Customer::find(1);

$cust->store->name;
```